# fontspec search path in TEXMFHOME

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, opentype

This is related to [fontspec (xelatex) finding fonts by name, installed or in TEXMFHOME](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132906/25670)

When installing an OpenType font in TEXMFHOME (~/texmf) I see the following behaviour with `fontspec` of TeXLive 2013 on Debian Linux :

Both xelatex and lualatex see the font when it's in
`~/texmf/fonts/opentype/emmentaler/emmentaler-16.otf`
but not when it's in
`~/texmf/fonts/opentype/lilyglyphs/emmentaler/emmentaler-16.otf`.

Is that expected behaviour? I recall it should be
`~/texmf/fonts/opentype/SUPPLIER/FONTFAMILY/FONT.otf`.

---

Comment: That's certainly unexpected. Subfolders shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hm. I checked more closely and found out that it seems to be related to symlinks. The `emmentaler/` dir is actually a symlink to the directory containing the font files (if it's relevant: on another partition). When this symlink is in `opentype/` both xe- and lua-latex find the font but when this symlink is in a subdirectory of `opentype` both *don't* find the font.

Comment: Oh this has just been discussed on the lualatex list last month: "Unfortunately, Kpathsea's subdirectory searching has an
irremediable deficiency: If a directory D being searched for
subdirectories contains plain files and symbolic links to other
directories, but no true subdirectories, D will be considered a
leaf directory, i.e., the symbolic links will not be followed.
You can work around this problem by creating an empty dummy
subdirectory in D. Then D will no longer be a leaf, and the
symlinks will be followed."

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Then the question is: is `~/texmf/fonts/opentype/FONTFAMILY/FONT.otf` an acceptable path for personal font files or should the `SUPPLIER` level be part of the path? (Both ways would work, but I have to decide what to write in the installation instructions.)

Comment: What people do in their local texmf tree is their own decision. If they have many fonts there some order is useful, but not necessary. So for most users a "somewhere below `~/texmf/fonts/opentype/` is quite enough. For the insecure users which ask for precise instruction and fret over small differences I would mention an example path like in the main texmf tree with SUPPLIER.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thank you, that's clear and solved now. Unfortunately there isn't anything to 'accept' or 'upvote'. Bye

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has just been discussed on the lualatex list last month:

> Unfortunately, Kpathsea's subdirectory searching has an irremediable
>   deficiency: If a directory D being searched for subdirectories
>   contains plain files and symbolic links to other directories, but no
>   true subdirectories, D will be considered a leaf directory, i.e., the
>   symbolic links will not be followed. You can work around this problem
>   by creating an empty dummy subdirectory in D. Then D will no longer be
>   a leaf, and the symlinks will be followed.