# TeX Gyre fonts in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX: call by name or file name?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Is there any downside of using file names with \setmainfont, except for the fact that it takes more typing?

I ask because I am experiencing problems with using names for TeX Gyre fonts on my Linux Mint box: as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132906/), XeLaTeX on Linux will not find TeX-installed fonts by name. Hence, I installed the fonts also system-wide (Ubuntu package tex-gyre), but the font names are different from my Windows box: the spaces are gone, so "Tex Gyre Termes" becomes "TeXGyreTermes" etc. This means that using names, the code becomes system-dependent :-(
(By the way, should this be considered a bug and reported to the maintainers of the tex-gyre package?)

On the other hand, calling the font by file name should work as long as the font file names are the same - can one trusts that? And is there any other potential problem with using file names?

Thanks

Comment: Similarly to the C/C++ `#ifdef _WIN32`, you can use [`ifplatform`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifplatform) to detect the operating system.

Comment: @marczellm Thanks, I did not know about ifplatform. But it does not really help, as I do not have any guarantee that the font names are constant across all linuxes, for example.

Comment: The disappearing spaces sound like a bug, where do you see that? But to answer your question, there is no downsides of calling fonts by file name.

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Linux Mint with the tex-gyre package version 2.004.1-2.1ubuntu1. Its called TeXGyreTermes system-wide, i.e. I see it also in LibreOffice etc.
Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Looks like a pretty old package from 2009!

Comment: OK, I see now. That package installs only the Type1 versions of the fonts, so them not being found is actually a good thing.

Comment: It might be an old package, but the OTF versions of the fonts are exactly the same as I get from freshly updated texlive.
Anyway, I have now removed the package and instead made the TeX OTF files visible system-wide, following [this guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4). Strangely enough, when I open Writer, the only TeX Gyre fonts with spaces in names are Bonum and the two math versions, the rest is without spaces ... which suggests that using file names is indeed a safer option.

Comment: For me (using Ubuntu 14, 16 and Debian unstable) it sounds like a Mint specific problem. I never observed problems like that on my systems and its packages.

Answer (score 2):

I discussed some of the problems and choices in my article in TUGboat 117 (vol 37 no 3, 2016) at http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117inn.pdf — it's basically down to how you work, what your workflow is, and how much you wish to trade off the conveniences of one against the inconveniences of the other. Basically, using filenames (and paths) ties your document to one directory structure, but it's more likely to be accurate for you. Using font names is supposed to be more system-independent, but they are sometimes weird and not always obvious.